# Return an empty promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, jquery-deferred

I have a function that returns a jQuery promise. It looks like this:

```
addBooks(books: Array<Books>) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/Books/AddBooks/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(books),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

I do this so I can reuse this function and chain promise callbacks like:

```
addBooks.done(() => { alert("Books added!"); })
```

My question is, what if I want to break out of addBooks early and prevent a trip to the server. For example:

```
addBooks(books: Array<Books>) {

    // An empty array was passed in for some reason.
    // Theres nothing to add so dont try to POST
    if (books <= 0) return null;

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/Books/AddBooks/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(books),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

My example will not compile because my chained done callback example is expecting `addBooks` to return a promise object, not null. How can I return an empty promise (or whatever the correct object is I should return in the situation)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> How can I return an empty promise (or whatever the correct object is I should return in the situation)?

Yes, an "empty promise" is appropriate here, if you mean a promise that is already fulfilled with nothing (`undefined`, `null`).

The jQuery syntax to create such is using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) with a single (or no) argument:

```
if (books <= 0) return $.when(null);
```

Comment: I didn't know of this usage of `$.when`, but it's right there in the docs!

Comment: `return $.Deferred().resolve();` is more correct answer.

Comment: @wonsuc Why do you think that, and how do you define "correct"?

Answer (score 8):

You can return a *resolved* promise: Instead of

```
if (books <= 0) return null;
```

use

```
if (books <= 0) return $.Deferred().resolve();
```

*Beware*, though, that jQuery's `Promise` API does something surprising: Sometimes it calls your `done`/`then`/etc. callback synchronously with the `done`/`then`/etc. call, sometimes it doesn't. Most promises libraries ensure that the call is always asynchronous, even if you're calling `done`/`then`/etc. on a resolved promise. jQuery doesn't, so you get subtle differences.

For instance, this code:

```
addBooks(() => console.log(1));
console.log(2);
```

...will log

```
2
1
```

...if you did the ajax call, but

```
1
2
```

...if you returned a resolved promise.

Comment: This compiles but I had to add additional code because the return type from `$.Deferred` is different from the return type of `$.ajax`. I like the answer @Bergi gave because its a little less code.

Answer (score 3):

From https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

> If you don't pass it any arguments at all, `jQuery.when()` will return a resolved promise.

e.g.

```
if (books <= 0) return $.when();
```

and, if you need a value that is not undefined passed on:

> If a *single argument* is passed to jQuery.when() and it is *not a Deferred or a Promise*, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks are passed the original argument.

e.g. an empty array is passed on:

```
if (books <= 0) return $.when([]);
```

e.g. an empty object is passed on:

```
if (books <= 0) return $.when({});
```